# Computing the definite integral of a fractional polynomial containing sin(x) and x^n

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I need to compute the definite integral defined as $$\int_{-\infty }^{+\infty } \frac{\sin ({x_0}\, \omega )-\sin (x \omega )}{(\sin (x \omega )-\sin ({x_0}\, \omega ))^2+(x-{x_0})^2} \, dx\,.$$

When  I try

```
Integrate[(- Sin[x \[Omega]] + 
    Sin[x0 \[Omega]])/((x - x0)^2 + (Sin[x \[Omega]] - 
     Sin[x0 \[Omega]])^2), {x, -\[Infinity], +\[Infinity]}] // \
Simplify
```

Mathematica cannot find the result.

So could you help me?
Thank you.

Comment: *Warning*:  This user does not mark any answers as accepted.  Proceed with posting answers to this user's question with due vigilance.

Comment: I am sorry for that because I don't know "flag or mak it as accepted answer". Now I understand how it works.

Answer (score 3):

A numerical solution, considering the singularity at `x==x0`, might be

```
int[x0_?NumericQ, \[Omega]_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[(-Sin[x \[Omega]] + Sin[x0 \[Omega]])/((x - x0)^2 + (Sin[x \[Omega]] - Sin[x0 \[Omega]])^2), {x, -\[Infinity], +\[Infinity]},, Method -> "PrincipalValue", Exclusions -> {x == x0}]

int[1,1]
(*-0.865516*)
```